# Python function to get or count the number of days between two years in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need a function to count the total number of days in the 'days' column between a start date of 1st Jan 1995 and an end date of 31st Dec 2019 in a dataframe taking Leapyears into account as well

For example:

- 1st Jan 1995 - Day 1
- 1st Feb 1995 - Day 32
- 2nd Feb 1995 - Day 33...

And so on all the way to 31st Dec 2019.

[image: Screenshot of the 1st ten rows of the dataset]

This is the function I created initially but it doesn't work.
`prices` is the name of the data frame and `'days'` is the column where the number of days is to reflect.

```
def date_difference(self):

    for i in range(prices.shape[0] - 1):
        prices['days'][i+1] = (prices['days'][i+1] - prices['days'][i])
```

Comment: Simplest way would be to parse the dates into datatimes using `pd.to_datetime`, then subtract the the first element from the column. That will leave you with a timedelta, which you can convert to seconds, then divide by the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: I can make a more specific answer if you make a [reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) (I don't want to re-type your data.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341) and please show us the output you want. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341). You can [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). BTW, for more tips, see [mre] and [ask].

Comment: @Nick No need to use seconds; timedeltas have a `days` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

#### Convert types

First of all, make sure that the `days` column is the proper type. Use `df.days.dtype` and it should be `datetime64`. If you get `object` type that means you have a string containing a date and you need to convert the type using

```
df.days = pd.to_datetime(df.days)
```

#### Calculate difference

```
df['days_diff'] = (df.days - pd.Timestamp('1995-01-01')).dt.days
```

Also, I would recommend changing the name of the column to date before it contains dates. Later you can assign the days to a column called so. It's just for clarity of your code and future maintaining it.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it to work by doing this:

```
def date_difference(last_day):
    last_day = pd.to_datetime(last_day, dayfirst = True)
    first_day = pd.to_datetime("01/01/1995", dayfirst = True)
    diff = last_day - first_day

prices['days'] = prices['days'].apply(date_difference)
```

Comment: `diff` is never used. It looks like you meant to return it. But why use this instead of Mateusz's answer, which is more idiomatic for Pandas?

Comment: Beside the point, but why are you using `dayfirst=True` when your data seems to be all in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).